# How can I get the keyboard to dynamically update when returnKeyType changes?

Tags: react-native

As a simplified example, I have a setup of

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ email: text })}
        returnKeyType={
          (this.state.email !== '' && this.state.password !== '') ? 'go' : 'next'
        }
      />
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ email: text })}
        returnKeyType={
          (this.state.email !== '' && this.state.password !== '') ? 'go' : 'next'
        }
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Then when I focus on the email field, I expect the Return key to say Next. And it does. And I enter text.

Then when I focus on the password field, I expect it to still say Next, and it does. And I enter text.

But now I expect it to change to "Go". But it doesn't. I've found an issue on RN that says I can change the `key` field on the `TextInputs` which technically changes the keyboard, but it also blanks out the input fields so that's not a useful solution.

How do I get the keyboard to update dynamically?

Comment: I'm gonna assume since the Keyboard itself is not a react component that it will not be affected by a rerender and the behavior you're looking for is probably not possible

Comment: That's a valid thought, but complicated by the fact that if I tab through my inputs in the simulator, the keyboard button does change. It just doesn't change as I'm typing.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this will solve your issue

```js
render() {
  let passwordReturnKey = this.state.password.length ? 'go' : 'next';
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ email: text })}
        returnKeyType={'next'}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })}
        returnKeyType={passwordReturnKey}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: not much significant difference with the code of jyurek